# Writing a generic binary search method

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

I have written this binary search method that returns the index of the `Book` object in an `ArrayList` where the `book id` matches the inputted `book id`.

How can I turn this into a generic method that takes a different type of `ArrayList` of object and search input as params and searches against that input? Is there a way I can generalize it?

```
 public static int bSearch(ArrayList<Book> a, String input)
    {
        int low = 0;
        int high = a.size() - 1;
        int index = -1;

        while(low <= high)
        {
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if(input.compareTo(a.get(mid).getID()) == 0) //input == target
            {
                //a binary search that returns index of min or max
                index = mid;
                return index;
            }
            else if(input.compareTo(a.get(mid).getID())) < 0) //input < target
                high = mid - 1;
            else if(input.compareTo(a.get(mid).getID()) > 0) //input > target
                low = mid + 1;
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at `java.util.Collections.binarySearch(...)`.  It should tell you everything you need. Source is available at GrepCode.

Comment: @JimGarrison This is for an assignment and I'm not allowed to use that binarySearch. If you know the solution, just nudge me in the right direction so that I can figure it out myself. Cheers.

Comment: I just did. Reread my comment carefully.

Comment: He is just suggesting you check implementation and you will find answer to your question

Comment: The type signature is a nudge in the right direction `public static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)`. You need to abstract your compare func

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do note that you're reinventing the wheel, a generic binary search is already implemented in [`Collections.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)).

With that in mind, for the sake of an exercise, sure it's possible to transform your implementation to make it generic, with a couple of changes:

- Declare type parameter `<T>`
- Make the elements of the input list have type `T` instead of `Book` (strictly speaking, `? extends T` will be ideal)
- Make the type of the element to search for `T`
- Add a comparator parameter, and use it to replace the comparisons on `Book::getID`

Like this:

```
public static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = list.size() - 1;
    int index = 0;

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        int cmp = comparator.compare(key, list.get(mid));
        if (cmp == 0) {
            index = mid;
            return index;
        } else if (cmp < 0) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

When you use this function to find a `Book` in a list by ID, you can write the comparator parameter as `Comparator.comparing(Book::getID)`.
(Needless to say, the list parameter must be sorted by book ids already, otherwise binary search won't make sense.)

Lastly, as [@nic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3716710/nic) pointed out in a comment, your implementation has a very undesirable behavior: when an element is not found, it returns 0. This is not so good, for two reasons:

1. It's impossible to tell if the element was found in the first position of the list, or not found. On a return value of 0, the caller would have to verify if the first element of the list (if exists) is equal to the searched element. That's ugly and painful.
2. It doesn't give a hint about the position where the missing element could fit in if inserted, which is a very interesting piece of information.

When the element is not found in the list, the common practice is to return `-1 -index`, where `index` is the position where the element *should be* if it was in the sorted list. You can implement this by changing the last line of the method:

```
return -1 - low;
```

For your follow-up question, if you wanted this method to take a book id string as the key to search for, then instead of a comparator, the third parameter could be a function that extracts the key from book instances. Then, instead of comparing book instances by a comparator, you could compare the key with the key extracted from instances:

```
public static <T> int binarySearchByStringField(List<? extends T> list, String key, Function<T, String> keyExtractor) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = list.size() - 1;
    int index = 0;

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        int cmp = key.compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(list.get(mid)));
        if (cmp == 0) {
            index = mid;
            return index;
        } else if (cmp < 0) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1 - low;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you breaking it down for me. I've been having some confusion with this concept. This somewhat clears it up. Cheers.

Comment: Just a note that you may also want to indicate failure to find the Book by returning a negative index in the case where the loop fails to match. In this case index will still be 0 which could confuse the consumer as 0 is a valid index.

Comment: @janos If I'm searching by `bookID`, does `T key` in the param represent the user inputted `bookID?` I also get an error on `Comparator.comparing(Book::getID)` saying non-static method can't be ref from a static context.

Comment: In my first proposal the key must be a `Book`. I added to my answer an alternative approach, searching by a string field, see my update. As for the error with `Comparator.comparing(Book::getID)`, it should work if you copy-paste my suggestion correctly.

Comment: @janos Thanks. Could you tell me which Java topic covers this issue in general? I wanna go over it on my own. Cheers.